# Box.net Api not returing the path of an image

Tags: php, box-api

I am managed to get tokens and using token to get the content from box.com site. I seen with other site like drop box,smug mug gives many versions of URL of images but here I am not seeing when I pull using the below command

https://www.box.com/api/2.0/folders/0?access_token= and the result is below.

I want to know the path of an image 20131228_181031.jpg in below data, I want to pull the image using php file_getcontent command for which I need image path.

```
{
  "type": "folder",
  "id": "0",
  "sequence_id": null,
  "etag": null,
  "name": "All Files",
  "created_at": null,
  "modified_at": null,
  "description": "",
  "size": 9985219,
  "path_collection": {
    "total_count": 0,
    "entries": []
  },
  "created_by": {
    "type": "user",
    "id": "",
    "name": "",
    "login": ""
  },
  "modified_by": {
    "type": "user",
    "id": "207866808",
    "name": "praveen",
    "login": " my id"
  },
  "trashed_at": null,
  "purged_at": null,
  "content_created_at": null,
  "content_modified_at": null,
  "owned_by": {
    "type": "user",
    "id": "207866808",
    "name": "Chandler",
    "login": "email@tbl.com"
  },
  "shared_link": null,
  "folder_upload_email": null,
  "parent": null,
  "item_status": "active",
  "item_collection": {
    "total_count": 5,
    "entries": [
      {
        "type": "file",
        "id": "12673472942",
        "sequence_id": "0",
        "etag": "0",
        "sha1": "a43eceb5de8ea1334aa545c95e92d7527f7bf163",
        "name": "20131228_181031.jpg"
      },
      {
        "type": "file",
        "id": "12673467202",
        "sequence_id": "0",
        "etag": "0",
        "sha1": "dfce2896cd97856fbe2755ec5b7e344103181e87",
        "name": "20131228_181034.jpg"
      },
      {
        "type": "file",
        "id": "12673477676",
        "sequence_id": "0",
        "etag": "0",
        "sha1": "dee70d192fc6bfec538d5581f8460005d7a79155",
        "name": "20131228_181938.jpg"
      },
      {
        "type": "file",
        "id": "12673481562",
        "sequence_id": "0",
        "etag": "0",
        "sha1": "a07e7c970ed0aa7fdab955aaad0d4e245d1595cd",
        "name": "20131228_181943.jpg"
      },
      {
        "type": "file",
        "id": "12673486582",
        "sequence_id": "0",
        "etag": "0",
        "sha1": "156446b911a22604b2a0c032888b4d7a6b6a3bfd",
        "name": "20131228_181957.jpg"
      }
    ],
    "offset": 0,
    "limit": 100,
    "order": [
      {
        "by": "type",
        "direction": "ASC"
      },
      {
        "by": "name",
        "direction": "ASC"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

On the Box API, when requesting a file, you do not need to know the folder it is in and so you do not need to build the path. You just make the request with the file id and include your access token in the header. For more info see the getting started docs [here](http://developers.box.com/get-started/#uploading-and-downloading).

A quick example using `file_get_contents` is below:

```
<?php

$fileId = 12673472942;
$accessToken = 'YOURACCESSTOKENGOESHERE';

$sBox = stream_context_create(array(
    'http'=> array(
        'header' => "Authorization: Bearer $accessToken\r\n" 
    )
));

$fileData = file_get_contents(
    "https://api.box.com/2.0/files/$fileId/content", 
    false, 
    $sBox
);

var_dump($fileData);
```

The `$fileId` is the `"id"` field in the JSON data you provided, so for the file you need it would be `12673472942`.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hi  Thanks for the reply,I am able to pull the images using the file id but I want to know the thumb image of the original images to be displayed in user interface before pulling it with fileid . How to get the thumbnail image of the original images from box.net which is only for display purpose not for pulling and the original image is for pulling from box.net. Please suggest

Comment: @user3165372 - Thumbnails can be grabbed via a similar method, have a look at this code for that - https://gist.github.com/madebydavid/8297808 The docs for thumbnails are here - http://developers.box.com/docs/#files-get-a-thumbnail-for-a-file

Comment: It works fine, The problem I am seeing here is the access_token which expires after 1 hr and I am not able to pull images after 1 hr and I used refresh token mehanism to get the token but that also lasts after 1 hr. Dropbox and smugmug is providing a token which can be used for ever but here the token expires immediately after 1 hr. Please suggest.

Comment: The refresh_token lasts for **60 days**, it is only valid for one use. You should store the refresh token when the user first authenticates. Then if they use your app again and their access_token has expired - get a new access_token with the refresh token and again store the new refresh_token you receive. If the user is returning to your app at least once every 60 days, they will never need to authenticate again. More details about the OAuth for Box can be seen here - http://developers.box.com/oauth/

Comment: If you have any more questions - maybe you should [post a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) so that others can answer too.

Comment: Thanks for the help.. Can you provide me the php command which makes use of secret key to get the token.The sample code that you provided above helped me a lot to make progress on this

Comment: @user3165372 - please post this as a new question via this link - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask